# Currying in Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying

I was manually writing a currying function in Haskell as follows.
`curry f = \x y -> f(x,y)`
Then I use this `max(x, y) = if x > y then x else y` as f, and I wrote `max1 = curry max` to get the curried function

But this is not allowed. Why is it wrong?

Comment: Your `curry` function works.  What error do you get?

Comment: Agreed, this should work.

Comment: OK, I figured out my testing function max1 is wrong. `max1 x y = curry max x y` works. I am new to Haskell, LoL

Comment: By eta reduction `max1 x y = curry max x y` and `max1 = curry max` should be equivalent in this case

Comment: But is `max1 = curry max` allowed in Haskell?

Comment: Can I define another function `max1 = curry max`?

Comment: Yes, you can confirm that e.g. by typing it into a ghci session: `let max (x,y) = if x > y then x else y; curry f = \x y -> f (x,y); max1 = curry max`. `max1` will have the type `(Ord a) => a -> a -> a`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ran into the [dreaded monomorphism restriction](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monomorphism_restriction), which limits where Haskell can infer polymorphic types.

A binding that does not "look" like a function—has no named arguments—cannot have a polymorphic type. The problem is that your `max` function *does* have a polymorphic type (it works for any type `o` that is in the `Ord` class), which forces the type system to pick a single concerete orderable type for `max1`. Since there is no default type to pick, it tells you a type variable is ambiguous.

There are three ways you can avoid this restriction. One, as you've already seen, is to make the arguments explicit, making the whole binding look like a function:

```
max1 x y = curry max x y
```

Another is to add an explicit type signature:

```
max1 :: Ord o => o -> o -> o
max1 = curry max
```

Finally, you can also turn off the restriction by adding a compiler directive to the top of your module:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

Out of all of these, the most idiomatic choice is adding a type signature. **Generally, every top-level name should have an explicit type signature.** This is not mandatory, but is considered good style because, apart from avoiding monomorphism issues, it also helps catch more errors and makes error messages easier to read. If you turn on all the warnings in GHC (with the `-Wall` flag), it will warn you about top-level names without type signatures.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know type inference worked differently in GHCi vs top-level of a module

Comment: Indeed, `-Wall` (or at least a subset of it) should be on by default, IMHO.

Comment: @NiklasB.: from a fairly recent version (7.6 or 7.8 or something), `ghci` has the monomorphism restriction turned off by default.

Comment: Thank you! The error ghci pops is something regarding the type inference I guess but I did not really understand why there was an error.

Comment: My `ghci` is version 7.8.3, but it still reported the error

Comment: @xwang: Yeah, it's a pretty obscure and unintuitive corner of Haskell's type inference that confuses almost everyone at some point. For now, just put type signatures everywhere and you'll be fine.

Comment: @xwang: `ghci` reported the error when you were loading your module. If you instead defined `max1` interactively by entering `let max1 = curry max` to the prompt, it should not give you an error.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis You are absolutely right. When loading modules it does not turn off the restriction but in `ghci` it does turn off.